# Can you use closures in an enum as params in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums, closures

if you have a function in Swift that takes a closure, can you force the param to be only what is in the enum like is done with an init()?

```
// function that takes a closure as a param

func calculator (n1: Int, n2: Int, operation: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int {
    return operation(n1, n2)
    }

// sample call.  Note: I'd like the closure to be an enum so that the programmer can only pick from items listed in the enum.

let myCalc = calculator(n1: 5, n2: 6 ) {$0 * $1}

// list of valid choices in an enum

enum CalcOptions {
    case Add {$0 + $1}
    case Subtract {$0 - $1}
    case Multiply {$0 * $1}
    case Divide {$0 / $1}
}

// Note: this gives an error (can't have the closure on the same line), I'd like the elements in CalcOptions to be closures.

// I can't do this because it's not a type listed:

var calcClosure: Closure {
    switch self {
    case .Add: return {$0 + $1}
    case .Subtract: return {$0 - $1}
    case .Multiply: return {$0 * $1}
    case .Divide: return {$0 / $1}
    }
}
```

If you wanted to restrict the usage to only those options listed in the enum, like you can when you setup an init(), how would you do that?

AFAIK, when you use enum in an init(), it makes it work like a data type such that the user of that init can only pick from the list that comes up.

I'd like to have the same functionality in a function, such that the user can only pick from the elements listed in the enum.

Example in a class where the customerChosenType is restricted to CarType in the init()... when the user selects this init, they get a popup in Xcode that restricts the input to the enum listing:

```
enum CarType {
    case Sedan
    case Coupe
    case Hatchback
    case FastBack
}

   init(customerChosenType : CarType){
    typeOfCar01 = customerChosenType
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift enums cannot have closures as rawValues, so you may need to bind each case and its corresponding closure in other ways, for example:

```
enum CalcOptions {
    case add
    case subtract
    case multiply
    case divide
}
extension CalcOptions {
    var operation: (Int, Int)->Int {
        switch self {
        case .add:      return {$0 + $1}
        case .subtract: return {$0 - $1}
        case .multiply: return {$0 * $1}
        case .divide:   return {$0 / $1}
        }
    }
}

func calculator (n1: Int, n2: Int, option: CalcOptions) -> Int {
    return option.operation(n1, n2)
}
print(calculator(n1: 2, n2: 3, option: .add)) //->5
```

---

Or, if you are using Swift 5+, you can make your enum *callable*:

```
@dynamicCallable
enum CalcOptions {
    case add
    case subtract
    case multiply
    case divide

    func dynamicallyCall(withArguments args: [Int])->Int {
        let n1 = args[0], n2 = args[1]
        switch self {
        case .add:
            return n1 + n2
        case .subtract:
            return n1 - n2
        case .multiply:
            return n1 * n2
        case .divide:
            return n1 / n2
        }
    }
}

func calculator(n1: Int, n2: Int, operation: CalcOptions) -> Int {
    return operation(n1, n2)
}
print(calculator(n1: 2, n2: 3, operation: .multiply)) //->6
```